# Finding the period of decimal

Tags: decimal-expansion, formal-power-series

Let $f$ be a formal power series with every coefficient either 0 or 1 , $f(2/3)=2017/(2^{2018})$. Find the period of decimal of $f(1/2)$.

I am new to power series but i searched all properties of formal power series but could not find any way to solve the problem.

Comment: Is this from a contest?

Comment: Yes. STEMS organised by the students of Chennai Mathematical Institute, India.

Comment: Is it ongoing? Anyway, this problem has very little to do with formal power series.

Comment: No. It has ended.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d_n$ be the sequences in $\{0,1\}$ such that
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n x^n$$
If $d_n$ is a periodic sequences in $\{0,1\}$ with period $T>0$ then
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac 23\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n\left(\frac 23\right)^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^T d_{kT+n}\left(\frac 23\right)^{kT+n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac 23\right)^{kT}\sum_{n=1}^T d_n\left(\frac 23\right)^n\\
&=\frac{3^T}{3^T-2^T}\sum_{n=1}^T d_n\left(\frac 23\right)^n\\
&=\frac 1{3^T-2^T}\sum_{n=1}^T d_n 2^n 3^{T-n}
\end{align}
is a rational number with odd denominator.
The same conclusion holds also for $d_n$ eventually periodic.
Thus, in order to have $f(2/3)=2017/2^{2018}$, the sequences $d_n$ must to be aperiodic.
Consequently, the number
$$f\left(\frac 12\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n\left(\frac 12\right)^n$$
is irrational because the $d_n$ are its binary digits.
Then the period decimal of $f(1/2)$ is infinite.

Comment: I guessed it will be infinite but couldnt prove. Thank you.